# How can I run a custom .sh script at each startup (without native init.d support)?

Tags: boot, scripts, init.d

This looks like a general concern of rookie Android system players who have just rooted their phones. The most prevalent method may be throwing your script into `/system/etc/init.d`. If the ROM supports `init.d` then Voila but that's not always the case. So

How can I run my custom script at each startup? What's the user/group my script will be running as if I use your solution?

---

We welcome all kinds of solutions.

Comment: [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way (working):

1. Prepare your post boot commands in a script, say /system/xbin/post-boot (set exec perm)
2. Add the above custom script path at the end of /system/etc/init.qcom.post_boot.sh

Eg:

```
# echo /system/xbin/post-boot >> /system/etc/init.qcom.post_boot.sh
```

Done!

(If you can't find the qcom post_boot (Qualcomm devices), look for any post_boot scripts)

Answer (score 2):

I think that most easy way would be by using app [Kernel Adiutor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grarak.kerneladiutor). It has ability to emulate init.d
Open app and swipe from left edge, it will reveal menu, scroll to tools section and than tap on init.d 
There you have a switch to enable or disable init.d emulator, for devices that doesn't support init.d, in bottom right you have a "plus" icon to add scripts to run.

Comment: Good job suggesting KA. I tried it but didn't know what to do months ago.

Answer (score 1):

From [my answer](/a/173970/205764) on another question, I have two methods here.

#### 1. Add `init.d` support manually by editing `init.rc`

I haven't done this ever personally but I can tell that

- You need to unpack and repack your boot image. This may not be very hard if you can learn from the SuperSU zip package.

#### 2. Replace a system service (in this case, the script will always be run as root)

Replace a system service (`debuggerd` is the best choice) binary with your custom shell script. Then run `start debuggerd` to activate it (effective from next boot).

If there's a `debuggerd64`, be sure to replace it with a null script.