# How to enable "Disable HW overlays" at startup?

Tags: android-10, scripts, developer-options

Question is simple, is there an easy way to enable developer options on startup from a command line script or 3rd party app? I want to set the flag for 'Disable HW overlays' on startup because it gets turned off every-time I restart the system.

For reference I am on Android 10, with bootloader unlocked, custom recovery, and rooted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Source-reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/aac03o/automatically_enable_a_developer_setting_on_boot/), which references [Android documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/73d3ba9)

> to DISABLE the h/w composer:
> `adb shell service call SurfaceFlinger 1008 i32 1`

> to ENABLE the h/w composer:
> `adb shell service call SurfaceFlinger 1008 i32 0`

These need to be run as root and can be in a [script](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/182030/131553) or using the Termux Boot app as [described in wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Boot)

For some reason, this works the opposite way for OP (command for enable disables and vice-versa ; maybe a case for a separate question)